# How do I view the manual page for Firefox snap

Tags: 22.04, firefox, snap, manpage, documentation

I'm using Firefox 113.02 on Ubuntu 22.04.

These commands produce nothing:

```
._. man firefox
No manual entry for firefox

._. find  / -name "man" -xdev 2>/dev/null | grep firefox
```

I can see three snap dirs among my system files:

```
._. find / -type d -xdev -name "snap" 2>/dev/null
/home/bonzo/snap
/var/snap
/snap
```

If I search in `/snap` for man files and dirs with `._. find  /snap -name "man" 2>/dev/null`, I find they do exist for most default snaps - i.e. Chromium, cups, snapd and "/snap/core20".

(Those man pages that do seem to be there are not readily accessible, however).

```
._. man chromium
No manual entry for chromium
```

What must I do to read the Firefox manpage now that it is installed as a snap?

Comment: I've found that for other snaps, the manpages were located at: `/snap/<snap-name>/current/share/man`. However, I've also experienced that not all snap applications has the manpages included. I believe it's a [known issue](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/support-for-man-pages/2299).

Comment: Yes indeed, there are fixes to activate manpages for apps installed via snap if the manpages are actually there...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there isn't one and any references to a firefox manpage would have been created so that firefox meets the requirements of a standard package.